# Is there a way to upload multiple images from Postman(API) in Laravel 6

Tags: mysql, api, rest, postman, laravel-6

I am trying to upload mutiple images from postman to a Laravel API, I expect it to store the image files in 'public/images' folder and save the name of the images in one column separated by coma in a fishponds table in MySQL database through a PUT method. However, the image is not uploaded and name of images are also not saved in database table.

Controller:

```
public function uploadpond(Request $request, $id)
{
    $fishpond = auth()->user()->fishponds()->find($id);
    $data = [];
    if($request->hasfile('pondImages'))
    {
        foreach($request->file('pondImages') as $key=>$files)
        {
            $name=$files->getClientOriginalName();    
            $files->move('public/images', $name);      
            $data[$key] = $name; 
        }
    }
    $pond=implode(",",$data);
    $fishpond->pondImages=$pond;
    $fishpond->save();
        return response()->json([
            'data' => $pond,
            'message' => 'success'
        ], 500);
}
```

Route:

```
Route::put('fishponds/uploadpond/{id}','FishpondController@uploadpond');
```

Postman Body:
[postman form body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZlNf.png)
Postman Header: 
[postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWwYU.png)

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? How is this related to MySQL?

Comment: I tried debuging. It seems the $data is empty outside for loop. MySQl relation is that nothing is saved to my database table